# Erro em Projeto de Curso primeFaces AlgaWorks

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou Fazendo um Workshop de `PrimeFaces` pela empresa `AlgaWorks`, mas está aparecendo este erro no projeto  no arquivo `pom.xml`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código completo do arquivo `pom.xml`

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cursoprimefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>iniciando-primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-m03</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>5.1</version>  
            <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1</version>
                       <configuration>
                          <source>1.8</source>
                          <target>1.8</target>
                       </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Voce já tem o arquivo `web.xml`?

Comment: Outra coisa, tira esse  "insira o código aqui" que está na frente da `dependency`

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro **`web.xml` *not found*** é um erro do `maven-war-plugin`, existe o arquivo `web.xml`? Se não existe e não deveria existir, configure o plugin para

```xml
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
```

Adicionando isso dentro do project -> plugins:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>false</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Obs: só verifica a versão do seu plugin

Answer (score 0):

Caso ocorra o erro no war deve-se clicar com o mouse direito em 
1 - Project explorer
2 - botao direito em deplyment descriptor
3 - generate deployment descriptor stub

Cria-se um arquivo xml que corrige o erro, caso persista, crie novamente o arquivo.